# Get the email address from SharePoint list and build Table inside Power Apps instead of hard-coding the values

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-formula, power-platform

We have the following Collection which contain a Type and Table of Email addresses inside Power App formula, with email addresses been hard coded, as follow:-

```
ClearCollect(
    varUserForContracts,
    {
        Type: "Admin",
        Emails: Table(
            {UEmail: "app.admin@.org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
            {UEmail: ".org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
           {UEmail: "app.admin@.org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
            {UEmail: ".org"},
            {UEmail: "*****.org"},
        )
    }
);
```

now instead i created a SharePoint list which include all the above emails:-

[image]

so how i can build the same Collection but to populate the table values from the values inside the SharePoint list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd recommend not using the `Title` column of the Sharepoint List.

   - `Title` isn't intuitive enough for code.
2. I'd also recommend the `col` prefix for Collections. Use `var` prefix for Variable, but don't mix them.
3. Add an `EmailAddress` and `EmailType` column to the List, populate their values.
4. Add the Sharepoint List to the PowerApp as a data source

   - `View/Data Sources/Add data source`
5. `OnStart` of the `App` control, add the following:

```
ClearCollect(colEmails,
  Filter(
      <YOUR_SHAREPOINT_LIST_NAME_HERE>,
      EmailType = "Admin"
  )
);
```

**Beware**.

- IIRC the `Filter()` function is not [Delegable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview) to the Sharepoint server. This means that the heavy lifting is done by PowerApps itself. That means you can only `Filter()` Sharepoint Lists up to the number shown in `File/Settings/Data row limit` (500 by default, 2000 max.).
- If the list exceeds that value, the `Filter()` only works on the first 500 up to 2000.
- Obviously this won't be the case with an "Admin Email List", but when you start getting all gung ho, remember these words.
- You *can* pull in large numbers of Sharepoint List records by using multiple `ClearCollect()`'s up to the 500-2000 limit, but at that point, ask yourself why do users need to peruse thousands of records in a mobile app!
- Hint: They likely don't. Adding another filter to **ALWAYS** reduce the number below the `Data row limit` is the best option in terms of simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
ClearCollect(
    varUserForContracts,
    {
        Type: "Admin",
        Emails: ForAll(SharePointListSource, {UEmail: Title})
    }
);
```

Where `SharePointListSource` is the name of your SharePoint list data source.

**Documentation**: [ForAll function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-forall)